# CORS did not succeed? How can i prevent that?

Tags: c#, reactjs, nginx, axios

I want to send get request to .NET API which is working in Nginx server. But i can't get any response,only cors errors.

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:${port}/${api}`)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                response = res;
            });
```

When i send request like that. It gives me this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
reading the remote resource at
```

I have changed my code a bit. And this is like that:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:${port}/${api}`, {
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
                },
                withCredentials: true,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                response = res;
            });
```

And it gives me  CORS did not succeed error. How can i prevent that?

Comment: `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,`... true isn't a valid URL.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution for you from the front-end. This is for security purpose. What you need to do is allow cors in your .NET backend API server.

You can learn from here
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cors-in-dotnet-core/